# looping wise filter with multiple column by using R

Tags: r

`

```
PRODUCT <-  c("A","A","A","D","D","D","D","C","C","C")

x_1 <- c("A1", "A1","A1", "B10", "B10", "B10","B10", "C100", "C100", "C100")

Date <-    c('2013-01-01','2013-01-02','2013-01-03','2013-01-04','2013-01-05','2013-01-06',    '2013-01-07','2013-01-08','2013-01-09','2013-01-10')
TEMP <- c(89,98,76,87,65,98,47,33,28,10)

df <- data.frame(Date, TEMP, PRODUCT,x_1)

for (i in unique(df$PRODUCT)) {   
  plot(df[df$PRODUCT==i, "Date"], df[df$PRODUCT==i, "TEMP"],
       xlab = "Date", ylab = "TEMP", # base the axes on full data range
       main = paste("Plot of", i))  # Give each a title
}
```

I have dataframe like shown above. I applied this loop that return only product wise unique values (e.g filter product wise) now, what i want to do filter with multiple category column like not only for product column (e.g Product,Branch and Region wise filter )
can anybody help me how to do this by using loop in R?
this code works but only for product column now i want to filter with multiple columns.like X-axis contain Date and Y-axis contain TEMP column now i want to filter product and x_1 column only showing specific record for both filters.

Comment: It is not clear what you want to do, because if it were a matter of filtering now by branch all you would have to do would be to write branch instead of product. So it is necessary to make it more clear how filtering by branch or region would be different from what you have already accomplished.
Also branch and region are not contained in the structure you have shown. In order to help you it would be better if you explained how these attributes are a part of the structure of your data.

Comment: @dario this code works but only for product column now i want to filter with multiple columns.like X-axis contain Date and Y-axis contain TEMP column now i want to filter product and x_1 column only showing specific record for both filters.

Comment: Sorry, that was an error on my side. I deleted my misleading comment.

Comment: We can combine multiple criterias using `&` or `|` e.g. `df[df$PRODUCT %in% "A" & df$x_1 %in% "A1", "Date"]`. To expand from your example, we could add another `for` loop to cycle through all unique values of `x_1`. Or we could alternatively use `ggplot2` and it's `facet_grid` capabilities.

Comment: Did you want to put `x_1` in your data frame?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
cmbs <- expand.grid(unique(PRODUCT), unique(x_1)) # Creates unique combinations

for (i in 1:n){
  x <- df[df$PRODUCT==cmbs[i,1] & df$x_1==cmbs[i,2], "Date"]
  y <- df[df$PRODUCT==cmbs[i,1] & df$x_1==cmbs[i,2], "TEMP"]
  if(length(x)!=0 & length(y)!=0) {
    plot(x, y,
       xlab = "Date", ylab = "TEMP", 
       main = paste("Plot of", cmbs[i,1], "and", cmbs[i,2])
  }
}
```

Comment: This code will filter of both columns("Product" & "x_1")?

Comment: I think so. Try and let me know..dont forget to put `x_1` in your data frame, `df`.